# Mobile Hotspot on and off Android on Marshmallow

Tags: android, hotspot

I want turn on or off Mobile Hotspot by pressing a button On or button Off .I have written this code for setOnClickListner and Given Permission in  Manifest File.But i am not able to turn on Mobile Hotspot.I just want to turn mobile hotspot On without any configuration of hotspot or mobile data.My android Os version is Marshmellow.

```
    btnHotspotOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        @SuppressLint("WifiManagerLeak")
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                Method method = manager.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class,
                        Boolean.TYPE);
                method.setAccessible(true);
                boolean enable =true;
                WifiConfiguration configuration = null;
                method.invoke(manager, configuration, enable);



            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });
```

Following is the Manifest File:-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: do you use the run time permissions?

Comment: means i dont got your question? What is runtime permissions.

Comment: read the topic of runtime permission because you are working on the marshmallow...

Comment: I have given all the required permissions...i also provide  WRITE SETTINGS permission now...But still i am not able to turn on hotspot...I want to ask what is meaning of "WifiConfiguration configuration = null" .Is it correct or not.